# Laravel Http::get() method not retrieving data from external API

Tags: php, json, laravel, http

I'm trying to fetch data from an external API with laravel.
This is how I do it :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
[..]
$response = Http::get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies');
dd($response->json()); // it's null
dd($response->collect()); // it's null
dd($response->object()); // it's null

//for debugging purpose
$response->ok() // this output true
$response->successful() //this output true
$response->failed() : bool; //this output false
$response->serverError() : bool; //this output false
$response->clientError() : bool; //this output false
```

The request seems to work i do receive a response but without data, the file i'm trying to read from is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "title": "ea officiis ducimus",
    "year": 2029,
    "poster": "http://placeimg.com/640/480"
  },
  {
    "title": "ea laudantium cum",
    "year": 2016,
    "poster": "http://placeimg.com/640/480"
  }
]
```

By the way it's not a json i think it's just a simple file that contains this it doesn't echo with php json data.

Also this is what i get when i go to the link in the browser:
https://gyazo.com/fafd0e9f74a47785d48f360c7c7b3f33

UPDATE 1:this is what i get when i do this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/api/movies');
dd($response->getBody());
```

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:3000/api/movies

EDIT 2:
I hosted the same file in another external server that isn't hosted on the same server in a different port and this time it worked.

Comment: Can you try `http://localhost:3000/api/movies` in the browser or in postman?

Comment: this is what i get in the browser : https://gyazo.com/fafd0e9f74a47785d48f360c7c7b3f33

Answer (score 5):

Try below:

```
$response = Http::get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies');
$data = json_decode($response->body(), true);
dd($data);
```

**Update:**
As per the updated question and discussion, the problem is due to your laravel application is in homestead (vagrant) and the api is on localhost (outside the homestead). You can reach your host computer using IP `10.0.2.2` (if vagrant settings are default). Using this ip can resolve your problem.

Comment: it's still null, thanks for helping

Comment: What's the output of `http://localhost:3000/api/movies` in the browser or in postman? Can you add the screenshot of it in the question?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/fafd0e9f74a47785d48f360c7c7b3f33

Comment: `dd($response->getBody())` is also null?

Comment: no it's not this is what I get: ` .GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream^ {#2138
  -stream: stream resource {@887
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}`

Comment: I think your laravel application is in homestead(vagrant) and "http://localhost:3000/api/movies" is outside the vagrant. Right?

Comment: yes i'm not sure how it works but the laravel is not in the :3000 it's in localhost and then they built an api in the :3000 port they used a middleware "Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!" You're right.

Comment: @Eliendrel , did you get any solution for localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the returns from my endpoints always returned empty,

After searching a bit, I found some parameters that helped me

```
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies',  [
            'debug' => TRUE, // remove after test
            'timeout' => 100,
            'decode_content' => false,
            'headers'=>[
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ]
        ]);

        $bodyResponse = $response->getBody();
        $result = $bodyResponse->getContents();
        $result = json_decode($result);
        dd($result);
```

another alternative would be to create another instance of your local server in a second tab of the terminal like:

`php artisan serve --port 3001`

```
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get('http://localhost:3001/api/movies',  [
            'debug' => TRUE, // remove after test
            'timeout' => 100,
            'decode_content' => false,
            'headers'=>[
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ]
        ]);

        $bodyResponse = $response->getBody();
        $result = $bodyResponse->getContents();
        $result = json_decode($result);
        dd($result);
```

so the api call is on 3001 and the view is on 3000, but this is only a solution for localhost, in production, this is not necessary